# List sorting - two lists into one

Tags: python, sorting

I have to make two list. One with names (str) and second one with wage (int). And then, i have to sort the wages with the names. The problem is that, always when I do this, only wages are sorted.

```
names = ["Asia","Łukasz","Aneta","Ola","Mikołaj"]
wages = [15000,1500,200,14500,2600]

print("Here(should) be sorted list")
wages.sort()
for i in range (len(wages)) :
    print(wages[i],names[i])
```

To be clear, I want to set on hold these two lists into one and sort both of them. With the simple method as it can be. Without functions, sets, zips etc. Just with loops.

Comment: What is `zarobki`?

Comment: @L3viathan: I think the OP forgot to translate `zarobki` into `wages`.

Comment: Can you use `sorted` and supply a `lambda` for the key?

Comment: You're only sorting one list then expect the second list to be sorted as well. The lists are not connected in any way. If you want them to be connected, build a dictionary that links the wages to the names.

Comment: Use tuples.  Make a list of `(wage, name)` tuples and them sort them normally.  Tuples are naturally sorted by their first elements so you just have to sort them normally.  (This is an overcomplicated way of doing `sorted(zip(wages, names))`)

Comment: OP, I notice you calling `sort`, `range`, `len` and `print` with no regard for your own instructions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, no zips and sets. We'll do this the hard way.

First, make a copy of wages:

```
>>> wages_c = wages[:]
```

Sort the copy:

```
>>> wages_c.sort()
```

And now, iterate over the copy and find the corresponding original name:

```
>>> for wage in wages_c:
...     key = wages.index(wage)
...     print(wages[key], names[key])
```

This is stupid and will not work if you have either duplicate names or duplicate wages, but it doesn't use zip or sets.

#### Original solution:

We start with your lists:

```
>>> names = ["Asia","Łukasz","Aneta","Ola","Mikołaj"]
>>> wages = [15000,1500,200,14500,2600]
```

Merge them:

```
>>> names_and_wages = list(zip(names, wages))
```

Sort by the second element:

```
>>> names_and_wages.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

And print:

```
>>> for name, wage in names_and_wages:
...     print(name, wage)
```

Comment: Question says: "*Without functions, sets, zips etc. Just with loops.*". Yeah I know...

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna do this with just loops, You could implement some sorting algorithm by yourself and along the way, interchange corresponding elements in `names` along with `wages`.

Here's an example with Bubble Sort:

```
for j in range(len(wages)-1,0,-1):
    for i in range(j):
        if wages[i]>wages[i+1]:
            tempWage = wages[i]
            wages[i] = wages[i+1]
            wages[i+1] = tempWage

            tempName = names[i]
            names[i] = names[i+1]
            names[i+1] = tempName
```

Comment: So far this is the only answer that really gives in to the ridiculousness of the question. +1

Answer (score 0):

Alright fine. If you don't want to merge the lists in ANY way then you need to write a sorting algorithm manually that returns a sequence of moves you can apply to both lists to get them into the same order. You can simplify this if you only have unique elements in your lists by sorting one list then see where each element has moved to and apply the same changes to the other list as well.

**More sane answer**

You have two lists which have a dependency on each other, namely the position of elements in the list.

You need to decide by what you want to sort them, by name or by wage?

You can `zip` those two lists easily with loops

```
i = 0
merged = []
while i < len(wages):
  merged.append((wages[i], names[i]))
```

And then use `sort` with `key = lambda x: x[0]` to sort by wages and `key = lambda x: x[1]` to sort by names.

Comment: Pff? This perfectly explains how to `sort the two lists into one`.

Comment: `Without functions, sets, zips etc. Just with loops.`. Like I said. Did not read question.

Comment: Yeah, and also `without functions` and `len` is arguably a function. Does `lambda` count as a function? The problem is way too underspecified and badly asked. He could opt for writing a sorting algorithm manually that performs the same swaps to both lists or similar but that's incredibly stupid and I'm pretty sure that's also not what he really wants.

Comment: I don't disagree with that last part, but zips are specifically off limits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a functionality similar to [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html): sort a list of the indices into the correct order, and then use that to rearrange both lists:

```
inds = list(range(len(wages))) # This can be converted into a while loop that appends elements until `len(wages)` is reached
inds.sort(key=lambda x: wages[x]) # Or did you want names[x] here?
sorted_wages = []
sorted_names = []
for ind in inds:
    sorted_wages.append(wages[ind])
    sorted_names.append(names[ind])
```

You can use a key that selects either the wage (`lambda x: wages[x]` as shown) or the name (`lambda x: names[x]`) for sorting. If you really want, the first line can be replaced with something like

```
inds = []
count = 0
while count < len(wages):
    inds.append(count)
    count += 1
```

The results are as expected:

```
>>> sorted_wages
[200, 1500, 2600, 14500, 15000]
>>> sorted_names
['Aneta', 'Łukasz', 'Mikołaj', 'Ola', 'Asia']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one way is to build a dictionary to store the name and wage.

```
 names = ["Asia","Łukasz","Aneta","Ola","Mikołaj"]
 wages = [15000,1500,200,14500,2600]
 the_dict = {}
 for i in range(len(names)):
      the_dict[wages[i]] = names[i]


 wages.sort()
 sorted_names = [the_dict[i] for i in wages]
 #now, both names and wages are sorted, and you can print them

 for i in range(len(wages)):
      print(sorted_names[i], wages[i])
```

Comment: Not the only way, but certainly a way. The only problem is that I am not sure that dicts are somehow less off-limits than sets or zips.

Comment: Given OP's lack of response, I think we can safely vote to close the question as unclear. I am not going to downvote you because the more I read it, the more ridiculous the question becomes.

Comment: I wonder if the OP, who cannot use _functions_, is allowed to use _methods_, as in `wages.sort()` ...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: no functions, seriously... no `len()`, no `range()`, no `.sort()`

---

Initialize our stuff,

```
In [1]: names = ["Asia","Łukasz","Aneta","Ola","Mikołaj"]
   ...: wages = [15000,1500,200,14500,2600]
   ...:
```

compute the length of the list

```
In [2]: l = 0
   ...: for w in wages: l += 1
   ...:
```

perform a simple bubble sort, in which we swap elements not only in the list that we are sorting but also in the sibling list

```
In [3]: j = 0
   ...: while j<(l-1):
   ...:     i = 0 
   ...:     while i<(l-1-j):
   ...:         if wages[i]>wages[i+1]:
   ...:             wages[i], wages[i+1] = wages[i+1], wages[i]
   ...:             names[i], names[i+1] = names[i+1], names[i]
   ...:         i += 1
   ...:     j += 1
   ...:
```

and print the results

```
In [4]: print names, '\n', wages
['Aneta', 'Łukasz', 'Mikołaj', 'Ola', 'Asia']
[200, 1500, 2600, 14500, 15000]
```

In a bubble sort every subsequent inner loop operates on a shorter (by 1) sub list because the net effect of each inner loop is to place the greatest element of the current sub list in the last position available in it.

We need only `l-1` of those loops because during `l-1`-th inner loop we operate on a length 2 sub list and when it is completed the whole sublist is completely sorted.

The bubble sort is not an efficient algorithm but given the *homeworkicity* of the question I think it is more important to use a very simple algorithm than an efficient one.